# In kotlin how to do instant app feature?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, android-instant-apps

I need to do a new Android project in kotlin which support instant app feature how I could achieve that? It is a known issue from Google that you can't do a Gradle sync with the kotlin plugin and Instant Apps SDK. Is , this issue still exist?

Comment: Could you please post a link the problem you mention as `known issue from Google that you can't do a Gradle sync with the kotlin plugin and Instant Apps SDK`?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/6hun17/instant_apps_and_kotlin/

Answer (score 2):

I haven't encountered any issues in regards to Kotlin and Android Instant Apps.

Several of the publicly available Android Instant Apps sample apps are written in Kotlin.

See [hello-kotlin](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/hello-kotlin) and [browse through the samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps) for implementation details.

Comment: By using stable version of android studio 3 no issues seen. Thanks